# Which /etc zsh related files are safe from OS update overwrites?

Tags: macos, upgrade, zsh

We have added custom modifications to the `/etc/zshrc`, which work. The issue is following an OS update (for example recently went from 13.2 to 13.3), the file gets overwritten and we lose our modifications.

Does anyone know whether there is any other zsh related file in `/etc` that is safe from update related overwrites? We are eyeing `/etc/zprofile` as a possibility, but not sure if that is any less at risk? Does Apple provide any guidance here for system administrators?

Comment: The files in `/etc/*.d/` are usually safe, but this won't help you as none of these directories relates to shell startup. I probably would put custom modifications into `/Users/Shared/something` and then source that from each user's profile.

Comment: Precisely @nohillside We have three or four locations at work for various items we need installed and then call them in rather than placing them where Apple has full reign and cleans up occasionally.

Answer (score 2):

Apple’s guidance is make backups. Their guidance is also, place your customization in user library or `/usr/local` and not in `/private`.

To system administrators, it’s also test betas in the seeding program so you can see breakage and ask for help / alert them before general release.

- https://appleseed.apple.com/it

They generally won’t speculate publicly since if they write something then they are in a pickle if they need to make a change they didn’t anticipate. They’ve been burned a lot in the past when changes come so they’re quite circumspect now on details like you seek.

The seeding program is where to get feedback loops / what to test / what *MAY BE CHANGING* sort of guidance, but even if they change things in beta - those tests / decisions are not always final (nor are decisions they ship officially - just those retractions / reversals are far more rare.)

You'll want to place a script in `/usr/local` or use MDM scripts to test for and replace customizations like the one that got moved intentionally by Apple.

Comment: How do you call the script in /usr/local without requiring users to chnage their locl config files?

Comment: MDM trigger or writing a launchd task / cron task that checks for the required edits, exits quietly or removes itself if there's no work to do. It's a hack, but we've managed these sort of hacks from time to time when there's a fleet of 5000 Macs that we couldn't find another more elegant solution @mmmmmm

Comment: Do you have any Apple docs that cover this guidance?

Comment: Most are in Apple Seeding - so I'd let you sign up and accept the terms - I can't redistribute them @AndreM There used to be a support KB on directory structure, but now that things are firmlinked / snapshotted / SIP / protected / signed - it's not so generic and you can tell pretty easily what Apple doesn't want changed... They move it and tell you in the install log it was moved...

Comment: I suspect the issue which prompted this question is also responsible for my recent troubles; i.e.: "restoring" the default `/etc/auto_master` file (where I've made changes) after each upgrade to Ventura. Is this as pervasive as it seems? Is there any Apple documentation that covers it? Are "re-restoration" scripts the best answer? And apologies for all of these Q's in a Comment, but my Q on this topic was closed, so not anxious to go through that again.